# How to apply a CDB debugger command to each line in file?

Tags: windbg

I have a file that contains address per line. Now I would like to apply a certain CDB debugger command (actually SOSEX `refs`) to each and every address in file.

I can generate a script where each line is of the form:

```
!refs <address> -target
```

So, if my original file contains 10,000 addresses, then the script would contain 10,000 invocations of the `!refs` command.

Is there a better way?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debuggingtoolbox/2009/03/11/special-commandparsing-strings-files-and-commands-output-using-foreach/

Comment: `.foreach` might work as well, but its syntax is not so simple, so IMHO it does not add benefit in this case.

Comment: My suggestion would not eliminate the need for 10,000 invocations of the command anyway, so I suspect that the answer to the question is that there really isn't a better way than what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming i gathered a few address like this to a file

```
.shell -ci "uf calc!WinMain" awk "{print $1}
```

i have 623 address in the file

```
wc -l someaddr.txt
623 someaddr.txt

head -n 5 someaddr.txt
00211635
00211637
00211638
0021163a
00211640

tail -n 5 someaddr.txt
0023779c
002377a2
002377a7
002377ac
002377b0
```

lets assume i want to disassemble two instructions of each each address

i would do some thing like this

```
.foreach /f (place "e:\someaddr.txt") { u place l2 }
```

resulting in

head

```
0:000> .foreach /f (place "e:\someaddr.txt") { u place l2 }
calc!WinMain:
00211635 8bff            mov     edi,edi
00211637 55              push    ebp
calc!WinMain+0x2:
00211637 55              push    ebp
00211638 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
calc!WinMain+0x3:
00211638 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
0021163a 81ec580d0000    sub     esp,0D58h
calc!WinMain+0x5:
0021163a 81ec580d0000    sub     esp,0D58h
00211640 a164402600      mov     eax,dword ptr [calc!__security_cookie (00264064)]
calc!WinMain+0xb:
00211640 a164402600      mov     eax,dword ptr [calc!__security_cookie (00264064)]
00211645 33c5            xor     eax,ebp
```

tail

```
calc!WinMain+0x772:
0023779c ff1500132100    call    dword ptr [calc!_imp__InvalidateRect (00211300)]
002377a2 e92ba4fdff      jmp     calc!WinMain+0x778 (00211bd2)
calc!WinMain+0x778:
002377a2 e92ba4fdff      jmp     calc!WinMain+0x778 (00211bd2)
002377a7 a1ac402600      mov     eax,dword ptr [calc!calcSQM (002640ac)]
calc!WinMain+0x7fb:
002377a7 a1ac402600      mov     eax,dword ptr [calc!calcSQM (002640ac)]
002377ac 83482004        or      dword ptr [eax+20h],4
calc!WinMain+0x800:
002377ac 83482004        or      dword ptr [eax+20h],4
002377b0 e993a4fdff      jmp     calc!WinMain+0x804 (00211c48)
calc!WinMain+0x804:
002377b0 e993a4fdff      jmp     calc!WinMain+0x804 (00211c48)
002377b5 90              nop
```